# Select All From Table Except Specific Column/s Without Temporary Table

Tags: sql

I've been searching for a way to get all data from a certain table except for a certain column.

Is there a way to do this without creating a temporary table? I find this although creative, inefficient.

I found this but again it's creating a temporary table. I guess temporary table is okay as long as it not an actual table that I can access.

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM TABLE_NAME
ALTER TABLE #TempTable
DROP COLUMN COLUMN_NAME
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE TempTable;
```

Again, my goal is to avoid creating a temporary table where I would later delete it to make it seem 'data-like'. Sorry I'm not quite sure how to put it into words.

Comment: I think you're trying to describe a `VIEW`. Read about views and how to create them.

Comment: A temp table is a poor idea, especially when you're using it the way you are here. Learn to use SELECT properly (which very seldom includes SELECT *) and you won't have this sort of problem. You'll also vastly improve the performance of your SELECTs because they're not returning data that you're not going to use.

Answer (score 2):

Just select the columns you do want . . .

```
select . . .
from t;
```

You can create a view with the columns you want.